# How to get user input from the previous line in Python?

Tags: python, input, output

So I'm trying to get user input within a very basic container box made with dashed lines. For example:

(dashed lines)

Enter customer name: (customer input)

(dashed lines)

I want it so that the first and last dashed lines are printed first, and the user is able to input whatever into the second line. I searched for a solution for this but truth be told, I am not even sure what exactly to search for. I am aware that Python operates as a line-by-line language, but I am a beginner and hoping maybe it is possible to do this.

Comment: What's the problem? Just print the dashed line before you do `response = input("Enter customer name:")`

Comment: If you're trying to display the whole form before getting input, you need to use a library like `ncurses`. Or use a graphical interface like `Tkinter`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to design terminal displays and interact with the console, the curses library is probably what you're after: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Otherwise, I think you're best solution is to just print the second set of dashes lines after the user input.

Comment: Thank you so much! This seems to be what I am looking for.